# Parsing XML file for clustering in R

Tags: xml, r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to parse this XML file to use it for clustering in R:

```
<root>
  <event>
    <name>apache</name>
    <ip_source>188.185.15.192</ip_source>
    <date>02:17:45</date>
    <request>GET3</request>
    <status>200</status>
    <len>7965</len>
  </event>
  <event>
    <name>apache</name>
    <ip_source>157.90.39.64</ip_source>
    <date>02:30:01</date>
    <request>GET2</request>
    <status>200</status>
    <len>964</len>
  </event>
  <event>
    <name>apache</name>
    <ip_source>115.78.92.20</ip_source>
    <date>02:34:03</date>
    <request>GET1</request>
    <status>404</status>
    <len>295</len>
  </event>
 </root>
```

So I used the following code in R:

```
library("XML")
df <- xmlToDataFrame("file.xml" ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
distance  <- adist(df)
hc <- hclust(as.dist(distance))
groups<-cutree(hc, k=2)
result= df$date[groups==1]
result
```

And the result I get is:

```
[1] "02:17:45" "02:34:03" NA         NA         NA
```

The problem is I don't understand why NA appear, I would like to have as a result a list with only a first item "02:17:45" and a second one "02:34:03", something like this:

```
[1] 02:17:45 02:34:03
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df` has 3 rows and length of groups is 6. When we do `groups==1` observations 1 and 3 of groups are true hence the matching date objects
are returned but observations 4,5 and 6 are not present in `df` hence the `NA`

```
   df
   #    name      ip_source     date request status  len
   #1 apache 188.185.15.192 02:17:45    GET3    200 7965
   #2 apache   157.90.39.64 02:30:01    GET2    200  964
   #3 apache   115.78.92.20 02:34:03    GET1    404  295


   groups
   # name ip_source      date   request    status       len 
   #    1         2         1         1         1         1 

   groups==1
   #name ip_source      date   request    status       len 
   #TRUE     FALSE      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE 

   df[groups==1,]
   #       name      ip_source     date request status  len
   #1    apache 188.185.15.192 02:17:45    GET3    200 7965
   #3    apache   115.78.92.20 02:34:03    GET1    404  295
   #NA     <NA>           <NA>     <NA>    <NA>   <NA> <NA>
   #NA.1   <NA>           <NA>     <NA>    <NA>   <NA> <NA>
   #NA.2   <NA>           <NA>     <NA>    <NA>   <NA> <NA>
```

When we limit groups vector by length of `df` you get expected result. Will this suffice for you

```
  df[groups[1:nrow(df)]==1,"date"]
  #[1] "02:17:45" "02:34:03"
```